# Addition to an integer variable which already has a set value

Tags: c++, variables, addition

Its my second day of learning how to code. I chose C++ as my first language and decided to make a cpp project. This project has 4 question and 2 answers for each question (Yes and No). In the end it must cout you a result which depends on how many answers were correct. Everything i did was working except 1 thing.
So for example if you answered at least 3 of the questions incorrectly you will receive cout << "You are stupid";
And if the amount of incorrect answer is lower than 3 then you will receive a cout << "You are smart";

As i mentioned before, i did everything right except one thing.
In order to keep track of how many questions were correct/incorrect ive set a variable:

```
int amount_of_correct_answers;
amount_of_correct_answers = 0;
```

Then i made it so that if the answer is correct, it will add 1 to this variable

```
if(answer == true_answer)
{
 amount_of_correct_answers + 1;
}
else
{
 amount_of_correct_answers + 0;
 }
```

So in the end of the test you see the result(if you are stupid or smart). My question is:
How do i add/substract from a variable? How do i add 1 to a variable thats set as 0 if the answer is correct? Because the code i wrote above didnt work. I think i am on the right track and my problem is syntax because i have no idea how to add/substract to/from a variable with a set value.

P.S. Keep in mind that i am very new to coding as i mentioned before, so please explain it in simple words or an example. Thank you

Comment: `amount_of_correct_answers + 0;` is making me doubt that I understood the question correctly. What is it that you are trying to accomplish with that line?

Comment: i am trying to add 0 to a variable so that it doesnt change at all and stays in it's original form

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Roomba Then it sounds like you don't need the `else` branch at all.

Comment: Side note: since the others already answered your question, I would just add this: You do not need the else condition and the stuff inside it for your case.

Comment: @Scheff how do i check it as a solved question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this does:

```
amount_of_correct_answers + 1;
```

Is add 1 to the value of `amount_of_correct_answers` and discard the result.  You need to assign the value back to the variable:

```
amount_of_correct_answers = amount_of_correct_answers + 1;
```

Comment: Oh wow, what a quick response, this website rocks! :D
I will try it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a variable called `amount_of_correct_answers` you can increment/decrement it in 3 ways:

```
amount_of_correct_answers = amount_of_correct_answers + 1;
amount_of_correct_answers+=1;
amount_of_correct_answers++; // you could use also ++amount_of_correct_answers in this case and have the same result
```

Comment: there are more ways, but yes thats the 3 most common ones

Comment: btw I would make `++x` the default and if needed use `x++`

Comment: amount_of_correct_answers++ returns amount_of_correct_answers and add 1.
++amount_of_correct_answers add 1 and returns amount_of_correct_answers.

In this case it's the same, but if you do something like 
int var = ++amount_of_correct_answers;
int var = amount_of_correct_answers++;
you could see something different

Comment: @Roomba Concerning `amount_of_correct_answers++;`: [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec)

Comment: the first one worked like a charm, but i will try the other ones too just to get the gist of it